# Is there any way to tell if an entity has any relationships in EF4?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Using Entity Framework 4, is there any way to tell if an entity has any relationships associated with it?  Suppose Object A contains a list of Object B, being tracked by EF.  I remove one Object B from the list.  During SaveChanges, I want to find the Object B that was removed and no longer has a relationship to Object A so I can delete it.

Any way to accomplish this?